# Get all the button tag types

Tags: javascript, tags

Is there a way to get all the button tag and their types on a particular page using javascript?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have this code either in the load event of the document, or in the bottom of the HTML:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    let button = buttons[i];
    let type = button.getAttribute('type') || 'submit'; // Submit is the default
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried with the original answer with no success, so i use this :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
```

Example:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");   

for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {   
  console.log("Button: " +  elements[i].id);
}
```

```html
    <input type="button" id="alfa" value="alfa">
    <input type="button" id="beta" value="beta">
    <input type="button" id="gamma" value="gamma">
    <input type="button" id="omega" value="omega">
```

Answer (score 4):

As the answer from @jorgesys points out, use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

That returns an `HTMLCollection` instance. In modern JavaScript you can convert to an array and use `map`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button"))
  .map(b => b.getAttribute('type'))
```

That will return an array like `["submit", "submit", null, null, ...]"`

I recently needed to disable all buttons, which could be done using `forEach`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button"))
  .forEach(b => b.disabled = true)
```

Or to avoid the temporary array (which probably isn't something you should worry about), you could create this:

```
function forEachButton(func) {
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(let i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
        func(elements[i])
    }
}
```

Then disable all buttons with:

```
forEachButton(b => b.disabled = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".classname").length;
for (var i = 0; i < buttons; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".classname")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("clicked!");
  });
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.