# How can I change colors of buttons into one command?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of my buttons in my javascript, but using a forEach(), or a loop to get the buttons listed in my javascript now to be the color blue. I don't want to use HTML because I'm trying to practice using events. I also want to have the colors change to black when the mouse hovers over them, also using javascript an using the "mouseover". Thank you.
JS:

```
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">



</head>

<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
    <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="calcScreeng" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>


  </div>



 </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6564187/963994) and this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event), you can code like this:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {   
      //Event Listener for mouseenter
      console.log(buttons[i].id.lastIndexOf('number'))
      if( buttons[i].id.lastIndexOf('number')!=-1 || buttons[i].id.lastIndexOf('decimal')!=-1)
      {
      buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   
    // highlight the mouseenter target
    event.target.style.color = "blue";

    // reset the color after a short delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      event.target.style.color = "";
    }, 500);
  }, false);

  //Event Listener for mouseover
  // This handler will be executed every time the cursor
  // is moved over a different list item
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
    // highlight the mouseover target
    event.target.style.color = "orange";

    // reset the color after a short delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      event.target.style.color = "";
    }, 500);
  }, false);
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">



</head>

<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
    <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="calcScreeng" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>


  </div>



 </section>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an event listener to a button such as *mouse hover* or *click*, use the *addEventListener* method. Pass in the name of the event to listen to the method (e.g. *mouseenter* to detect hovering of a mouse) followed by the function to be called when that event occurs.

You can get all the buttons in a html page and store it in an array variable: 
    `var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");`

Alternatively, you can group your buttons by giving them a class or name attribute:
    `<button class="multiColorButtons">9</button>`
so that you can access them by their groups: 
    `var theButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("multiColorButtons");`

You can then loop through them and attach the event listener to change color:

```
for (let i = 0; i < theButtons.length; i++) {
     theButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
         event.target.style.display = "black";
     });
}
```